# Add Google Plus in header in html.tpl.php

Tags: php, html, drupal, google-plus

In html.tpl.php I have written :

```
<?php if($front_page):?>
<?php print '<a href="https://plus.google.com/109533530102750336693" rel="publisher">Google+</a> '?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but its not working moreover its hanging the home page.

Can someone please tell me the correct syntax if it has some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you not be using echo instead of print?

```
 <?php if(drupal_is_front_page()):
 echo '<a href="https://plus.google.com/109533530102750336693" rel="publisher">Google+</a>'; 
 endif; ?>
```

Comment: And also not using unnecessary php tags?

Comment: @blo - You're right, I wasn't thinking for a second!

Edited answer. Now to include the drupal front page check function.

Comment: Any reason why you've unmarked this as the answer? Considering it solved your issue.. ?

Answer (score 0):

In most themes, you should be overriding page.tpl.php rather than html.tpl.php. You also have a couple of errors in your syntax. The typical code for a template would read:

```
<?php if($front_page): ?>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/109533530102750336693" rel="publisher">Google+</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note the space in the first line, plus you don't need to print the second.

Comment: The $front_page variable is generally always provided by your theme for use in page.tpl.php. Do you need to be overriding html.tpl.php rather than page.tpl.php?